# Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug' in Ionic 3

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am getting build failure in Ionic 3.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
(node:5300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:775)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:741)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:88)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1683)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:695)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:560)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:376)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:290)
        at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:54)
        at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.lambda$dexInProcess$0(DexByteCodeConverter.java:173)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:476)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:787)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1600(Main.java:88)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1722)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:773)
        ... 16 more

Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:775)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:741)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:88)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1683)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:695)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:587)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:376)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:290)
        at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:54)
        at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.lambda$dexInProcess$0(DexByteCodeConverter.java:173)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:476)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:787)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1600(Main.java:88)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1722)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:773)
        ... 16 more
```

I saw that there are many solutions of adding **multiDexEnabled true** to **defaultConfig** in **build.gradle**. I tried but it did not work out.

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
    applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

    if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
        minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
    }

    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

I have tried also by deleting and reinstalling **node_modules**, **plugins** and **platforms** folder also but did not work out.

Can anyone please point me out here.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of messing about making changes to **project.properties** and the **build.gradle** file without getting anywhere I managed to solve it by doing the following:

**Remove Android platform:**

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

**Added latest Android platform:**

```
cordova platform add android@latest
```